# Debug Log Limits? Can I not reset the available request and watch log as many as I want?

Tags: configuration, debugging, debug

Do I have to create a record under "Monitored Users" when I want to debug something?  I didn't have to do this early this year and I was able to monitor as many debug logs as I want.

Can I not reset the available request and watch log as many as I want?

I want to make this happen for my own logs and preferably for all users logs.
20 log requests is exhausted quickly.

Comment: You can only do 20 log requests and the user needs to be added to the monitored users.

Answer (score -1):

@sfdcnoob No you cant. But when you refresh logs list page available request are refreshed either.